# If Condition logical error in multiple conditions in loop with cron

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, cron, logic

I need to run 2 loops in cron which work after every 5 minutes

```
*/5 * * *  *
```

loop by cron 1. work in every 5 minutes and check if the file is uploaded or not. ($yesterday mean file with name of backdate)

1st cron-loop work fine to me, 2nd cron-loop I am not able to resolve, 2nd loop have 3 conditions

**1. It should work when it found $yesterday.zip**

**2. It should only work once after $yesterday.zip (because its cron so it work after every 5 minutes when $yesterday.zip found)**

**3. it should not work 00:00 till $yesterday.zip downloaded**

($yesterday file has no fix time to download so i run cron every 5 minutes) 
I made this (writing below so you . guys dont think i didnt made effort and didnt say show sampel code, just need a if statement with cron include these 3 conditions)

```
FILE=/fullpath/$yesterday.zip
if test -f "$FILE"; then
touch /fullpath/loop2.txt ##########for loop 2
echo "I am the best"
else
cd /fullpath/
wget -r -np -nH "url/$yesterday.zip" ###########it should be 20+ mb file
find . -name "*.zip" -type 'f' -size -160k -delete ########## it will delete is some garbage downloaded
rm -rf /fullpath/loop2.txt  ########## delete the file so it stopped loop 2 for working evry 5 minutes .
fi

FILE2=/fullpath/loop2.txt
if test -f "$FILE2"; then
echo -e "Script will work only once" | mailx -v -s "Script will work only once"  myemail@gmail.com
else
echo "full script work"
touch /fullpath/loop2.txt
fi
```

You guys can ignore my above code and simple let me know if statement for such 3 conditons loop

Comment: Can you confirm that you want a cron task to download a 20+mb file once a day as soon as it becomes available, making sure it has downloaded the whole file before it does further actions, and then stop executing for the rest of the day?

Comment: @Aaron the actual file is 32-35 mb everyday

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this :

```
if lockfile -r0 /tmp/lockfile_$(date +%F); then #only run if there's no lockfile for the day
    cd /fullpath/
    # while we don't have a correct file (absent or truncated)
    while [[ ! -f "$yesterday.zip" ]] || [[ $(stat -c %s "$yesterday.zip") < 20971520 ]]; do
      wget -r -np -nH "url/$yesterday.zip"  # try to download it
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then # if the file isn't available yet
        rm /tmp/lockfile_$(date +%F) # delete the lock in order to attempt the download again in 5"
      fi
    done
fi
```